# Blueimp jquery-file-upload with Browserify and Angular

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, browserify, blueimp

Has anybody had any luck with using blueimp jquery-file-upload with browserify? I have the following requires in my javascript ...

```
require("jquery");
require("blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js");
require("blueimp-file-upload");
require("blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-angular.js");
```

and I get the following error when I use the resulting browserified code...

```
TypeError: $element.fileupload is not a function
```

... at the line ...

```
$element.fileupload(angular.extend(
```

... inside of `jquery.fileupload-angular.js`. Without browserify this was working fine. I can't figure out where the fileupload() function is being added to the prototype of the $element.

Comment: I ended up just using gulp-concat on the file-upload code instead of browserifying it. Still looking for the answer though.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you did to solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

By request I'm posting what I did here to get around the issue. So technically speaking not an answer but a "work around". As I indicated in my comment above I used gulp-concat along with gulp-uglify to do the minimizing "manually". I say manually because I have to list all of the source files here rather than relying on the requires.

```
gulp.src([src1, src2, ..., srcN])
.pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest(outputdir));
```